# Multiple form elements in different divs-- submitting one resets the others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am trying to do the following:
I have a page with multiple divs, each of which contains a graph and a form element (which contains a selector, which has a few options for how to configure the graph). 
Right now, when a user submits the form on one of the divs, the graph in that div changes as it should.  But if the user decides to submit another form in another div, then the forms in all other divs reset to their original values, ignoring any selections the user made.  I want the selectors to be able to remember their values so that even if a form somewhere else on the page is submitted, none of the other divs get reloaded.
Essentially, submitting a form should only reload the div it is inside, and leave the other divs as they are.  From what I've read so far, Ajax seems to be the solution to such issues, but I'm not entirely sure how to incorporate it into my code.  This is sort of what I am doing:

For each of the divs, I create the form dynamically:

```
    var form = document.createElement("form")
    var selector = document.createElement("selector")
    selector.setAttribute("onChange", "this.form.submit()")
```

(I also add the various options to the selector dynamically, but I am not including the code for that, bc that just involves appending options to the selector)

Then, later, the graph inside the div refreshes with new settings based on the value in the selector.

Please let me know if there are other parts of my code that I should paste here.  I figured that the relevant part was this part (setAttribute("onChange", "this.form.submit()") where the this.form.submit() is the main problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) The answer to this question will depend a lot on the HTML. *Show*, don't *tell*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Submitting a form tears down the entire page and replaces it with the result of submitting the form. That's not isolated to the `div` the form is in, it's a page-wide action.

If you want to have the page *not* refresh when the form data is sent, ajax is indeed how you would do that. You've tagged your question `jquery`, so here's a simple jQuery example:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(e) {
    // Don't submit normally...
    e.preventDefault();

    // ...and then submit via ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: this.action,
        type: this.method,
        data: $(this).serialize()
    })
    .done(function(result) {
        // It worked...
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // It failed...
    });
});
```